24.04 LTS - HP elitebook 1040 - Dell docking station WD22TB4 - ETHERNET
I'm running 24.04 LTS on a HP elitebook 1040 and a Dell WD22tb4 docking station.  I've had no initial issues with the Dock but because I've been using WIFI I didn't notice the ethernet port wasn't working.
My WIFI connection at work tends to be "experimental" so I can't rely on it.  But I've now discovered I can't get the dock's ethernet port to work.  Googling I've found I've got seemingly everything in place, and I can find no reason why it shouldn't work.
It seems like firmware could be the root of the issue.  But I seem to have everything in place.
I've also checked the BIOS to make sure there was no security enabled that might block access.
Any insight would be appreciated.
My stuff:
sudo fwupdmgr install DellDockFirmwarePackage_WD19_WD22_Series_HD22_01.00.20.cab
Decompressing…           [  -                                    ]
All updatable firmware is already installed

linux-firmware/noble-updates,now 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0b40 Intel Corp. USB3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 30c9:0096 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP 5MP Camera
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00f0 Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1d5c:5801 Fresco Logic USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:5487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:5413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 413c:b06e Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 413c:b06f Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

boltctl

 Dell WD22TB4 Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          WD22TB4 Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ vendor:        Dell
   ├─ uuid:          0aa28780-0019-30d9-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     38778780-415f-9115-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ rx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  ├─ tx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Mon 08 Jul 2024 11:31:24 AM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Mon 08 Jul 2024 11:31:23 AM UTC
   └─ stored:        Thu 02 May 2024 03:52:41 PM UTC
      ├─ policy:     iommu
      └─ key:        no

nmcli dev
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
wlp0s20f3          wifi      connected               ******
lo                 loopback  connected (externally)  lo
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --

